# MongoDB misses saving data in a long period of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Good afternoon, I have a script which is receiving data from [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) every 30 minutes and saves it in MongoDB specific database in different collections.
My MongoDB is installed on VPS. I'm connecting to it from my local computer.

Problem is that I leave my code to work constantly for ± 3 days and I receive that sometimes data did not save on specific collection or missed, etc. How I can configure my code or what can I do to create a perfect connection to save all data correctly.

Problem Explanation:
I have an array with

```
symbols=["ada","ae","kava","eth","etc","zrx","xzc","faq","gas","vfg","req"];
```

And when I leave the code for let's say 25 hours. I suppose to see 50 documents on every collection name.
But I receive that some collections got 48 documents saved instead of 50, some of them got 49, some of them got 50 like sometimes collections didn't save d properly.

**FULLCODE HERE:**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const symbols=["ada","ae","kava","eth","etc","zrx","xzc","faq","gas","vfg","req"];

//a descriptive name helps your future self and others understand code easier
const getBTCData = async symbol => { //make this function accept the current symbol
    //async/await lets us write this much nicer and with less nested indents
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=30m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
            High: parseFloat(d[2]),
            Low: parseFloat(d[3]),
            Close: parseFloat(d[4]),
            Volume: parseFloat(d[5]),
            Timespan: 30,
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata);
    saveToDatebase(symbol, btcusdtdata);
    //recursive functions are complicated, we can get rid of it here
    //by moving the responsibility to the caller
};

//helper function for an awaitable timeout
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/30 * * * *', async() => {
    //expand this function to be responsible for looping the data
    for (let symbol of symbols) {
        //we can pass symbol to getBTCData instead of making it
        //responsible for figuring out which symbol it should get
        await getBTCData(symbol);
        await sleep(8000);
    }
});

//make this a helper function so `saveToDatabase()` isn't also responsible for it
const getDateTime = () => {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return date + ' ' + time;
};

const saveToDatebase = async(symbol, BTCdata) => {
    const url = 'mongodb://username:password@server:port/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
    let dateTime = getDateTime();

    //use await here and below to vastly simplify this function
    let db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
    const myobj = { Name: symbol, Array: BTCdata, Date: dateTime };
    await dbo.collection(symbol).insertOne(myobj);
    console.log('1 document inserted');
    db.close();
};
```

Goal: Solve the saving issue, I think it also can be possible something with VPS response itself. How can I maybe update my code that it looks cleaner and faster if possible?

Any suggestions or help really appreciated.

Comment: you should see some `unhandledRejection` in the console, is that correct?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Hard to answer, cause it was all the time at the night and when I get to my console, I can't scroll till error. Currently I'm trying to make a file which is going to save a log of all terminal data

Comment: you could just run your node with `node schedule &> output.log`. Anyway the code could be optimized to retry. the interesting things would be to know if it is a db error (I don't think) or a fetch problem (more likely)